# Powershell - MSExchange Set-Contact How to throw an error when cmdlet returns error message

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-cmdlet

I have the following code that updates contact records in MS exchange. My goal is that if it fails to update the record, it goes into my catch block to log that there was an error. Instead, it's just returning the following in the log and moving on, not going to the catch block. I'm newer to powershell but i'm assuming the error msg is not a ps exception, and is reporting the error on the external cmdlet. Is there any way to check that the cmdlet encountered and error so I can log it/go down an error path?

snippet of code I'm running:

```
try{

$msxchangeInfo = Get-Contact | Where-Object {$_.WindowsEmailAddress -eq  "$user_search_email"}

if ($msxchangeInfo)
{
write-host "$(Get-TimeStamp) $user_search_email found...."

$msxchangeInfo = Get-Contact -Filter "WindowsEmailAddress -eq '$($user_search_email)'" | 
Select-Object -Property WindowsEmailAddress, Manager, FirstName, LastName, MobilePhone, 
DisplayName, Company, Department, Identity, StreetAddress, StateOrProvince, PostalCode, 
CountryOrRegion, City, Phone


$msxchangeInfoCountryOrRegion = $msxchangeInfo | Select -ExpandProperty CountryOrRegion

    if($msxchangeInfoCountryOrRegion -ne $officeCountry -and $officeCountry -ne "")
{

/*CODE THAT IS RETURNING ERROR MESSAGE BUT NOT THROWING EXCEPTION!*/
Set-Contact -Identity $msxchangeInfoIdentity -CountryOrRegion $officeCountry}

}
}
catch
{
write-host("$(Get-TimeStamp) *****ERROR*****: ERROR ATTEMPTING TO CREATE NEW CONTACT RECORD: 
$($displayName) . CHECK ERROR BELOW")
write-host($_.Exception|format-list -force)
write-host("$(Get-TimeStamp) Adding user to error ticket list")
$errMsg = $error[0].ToString() + $error[0].InvocationInfo.PositionMessage
$errMsg -replace ',','|'
}
```

However the code is never hitting the catch block. It is not throwing an error, it's just logging the cmdlet error message and continuing. How do I break it on the cmdlet error of set-contact?

This is the output in the log (as you can see, not logging my custom error message noted above):

```
Account                              Environment TenantId                             TenantDomain  AccountType     
-------                              ----------- --------                             ------------  -----------     
gggggggggggggg-gggggg-ggggggg-gg AzureCloud  gggggggggggg-ggggg-gggg-gg TestTenant.com ServicePrincipal
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'CountryOrRegion'. Cannot convert value "Not Found" to type 
"Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.CountryInfo". Error: "The ISO-3166 2-letter country/region code or friendly name 
"Not Found" does not represent a country/region."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Contact], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-Contact
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Comment: `Set-Contact ... -ErrorAction Stop`

Comment: I think you have to tell powershell which errors to catch. This code will catch all error ```catch [System.Exception]```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks a ton!! That solved my problem. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force a specific call to a cmdlet to halt on error via the `-ErrorAction` common parameter:

```
Set-Contact -Identity $msxchangeInfoIdentity -CountryOrRegion $officeCountry -ErrorAction Stop
```

You can also set this as the default behavior for any call in the current scope by modifying the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable at the start of your script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

... or, alternatively use the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` variable to make *specific* cmdlets in the current scope always take on this behavior on error:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Set-Contact:ErrorAction'] = 'Stop'
```

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed my issue! Great answer!!